# Responsive Tooltip with Tooltip Hover

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, hover, tooltip, clickable

I have setup this code in order to work with a shortcode/plugin I'm building for WordPress...everything is finally working well with responsive (this is the third jQuery revision), but I'm having an issue with one thing: Hovering on the tooltip.

I need to be able to mouse into the tooltip and have it stay visible. I need the tooltip to go away if:

a. The tooltip is moused out of, or..
b. The target is moused out of

jQuery is not my strong suite and I can only get one or the other to happen.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="mbt-hover" style="width:100px; height:auto;">
    <p>Test Text</p>
    <div class="mbt-tooltip" style="width:200px; height:auto;">
        <p>Test pop-up <a title="About" href="http://www.mindblowingthings.dev/about/">content</a>
        <ul>
            <li>this</li>
            <li>is</li>
            <li>a list</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#tooltip {
text-align: center;
color: #fff;
background: #111;
position: absolute;
z-index: 100;
padding: 15px;
}

#tooltip:after {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid #111;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: -10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
}

    #tooltip.top:after {
        border-top-color: transparent;
        border-bottom: 10px solid #111;
        top: -20px;
        bottom: auto;
    }

    #tooltip.left:after {
        left: 10px;
        margin: 0;
    }

    #tooltip.right:after {
        right: 10px;
        left: auto;
        margin: 0;
    }


.mbt-tooltip {
display: none;
width: auto;
max-width: 100% !important;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$( function() {

    var targets = $('.mbt-hover'),
        target  = false,
        tooltip = $('.mbt-tooltip'),
        title   = false;

    targets.bind( 'mouseenter', function()
    {
        target  = $( this );
        tip     = target.children('.mbt-tooltip');
        tooltip = $( '<div id="tooltip"></div>' );

        if( !tip || tip == '' )
            return false;

        //target.remove('.mbt-tooltip');
        //target.removeAttr( 'title' );
        tooltip.css( 'opacity', 0 )

               .html( tip.clone().show() )

               .appendTo( 'body' );

        var init_tooltip = function()
        {
            if( $( window ).width() < tooltip.outerWidth() * 1.5 )
                tooltip.css( 'max-width', $( window ).width() / 2 );
            else
                tooltip.css( 'max-width', 340 );

            var pos_left = target.offset().left + ( target.outerWidth() / 2 ) - ( tooltip.outerWidth() / 2 ),
                pos_top  = target.offset().top - tooltip.outerHeight() - 20;

            if( pos_left < 0 )
            {
                pos_left = target.offset().left + target.outerWidth() / 2 - 20;
                tooltip.addClass( 'left' );
            }
            else
                tooltip.removeClass( 'left' );

            if( pos_left + tooltip.outerWidth() > $( window ).width() )
            {
                pos_left = target.offset().left - tooltip.outerWidth() + target.outerWidth() / 2 + 20;
                tooltip.addClass( 'right' );
            }
            else
                tooltip.removeClass( 'right' );

            if( pos_top < 0 )
            {
                var pos_top  = target.offset().top + target.outerHeight();
                tooltip.addClass( 'top' );
            }
            else
                tooltip.removeClass( 'top' );

            tooltip.css( { left: pos_left, top: pos_top } )
                   .animate( { top: '+=10', opacity: 1 }, 50 );
        };

        init_tooltip();
        $( window ).resize( init_tooltip );


       var remove_tooltip = function()
        {
            tooltip.animate( { top: '-=10', opacity: 0 }, 300, function()
            {
                $( this ).remove();
            });

            target.children('.mbt-tooltip', tip);

        };

        //**** ISSUE AREA ****//
        target.bind( 'mouseleave', remove_tooltip );
        tooltip.bind( 'click', remove_tooltip );
    });
});
```

**FIDDLE:**
http://jsfiddle.net/RevConcept/L8bho8yu/

Comment: `tooltip = $( '<div id="tooltip"></div>' );` - what is this? Did you mean `tooltip = $( '#tooltip' );`?

Comment: No, it's correct - it creates a new div with the id #tooltip.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36275678/how-to-create-a-tooltip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because the `tooltip` that you create on `mouseenter` event of `.mbt-hover`

```
tooltip = $( '<div id="tooltip"></div>' );
```

is a new element that you append to the `body`. Because it's not a child of `.mbt-hover`, when you try to hover over the `tooltip`, it will trigger the `mouseleave` event of `.mbt-hover`, thus removing the `tooltip`.

What you need to do is to append the new `tooltip` that you create to the `.mbt-hover`, and not to the `body`, so when you hover over the `tooltip`, it still count as `mouseenter` on `.mbt-hover` and wouldn't remove the `tooltip`. (*Note: this will results the same only if your `tooltip` `absolute position` is `relative` to the `body` and not to the parent container, if your `tooltip` position is `relative` to it's parent, you need to change your code to calculate the `top`, `left`, or `right`)

You also have some redundant `code`, for example:

1. `var targets = $('.mbt-hover')` with `target  = $( this );`, this two variable is pointing / targetting to the same element which is `.mbt-hover`, so it's better for you to only use the `targets` for every usage inside the `mouseenter` event by replacing the `target` to `targets`.
2. Because you already have a `tooltip` in your `HTML` with class `.mbt-tooltip`, it's better to use it for the `tooltip`, rather then creating a new `tooltip` element that clone the one that you have already (Because on `document ready`, you declare it with `tooltip = $('.mbt-tooltip')`, but then on the `mouseenter` you change it with `tooltip = $( '<div id="tooltip"></div>' );`

Here's the [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyojimaru/L8bho8yu/1/) of yours which is removed from the redundant `code` on point number one.

Comment: Ahhhh! Genius :) I never even thought of that. Thank you SO much and thank you for the very detailed answer with explanation!

Comment: Actually, there was an issue because there can be more than one tooltip on the page and your code was combining the tooltip content into one tip. I updated it: http://jsfiddle.net/RevConcept/x8vz6kdy/1/

Comment: @RevConcept, did you embed all your tooltip inside every `mbt-hover`, and every `tooltip` has the same template? If yes, I think it's better to embed it as `data` attribute in the `mbt-hover` (e.g.: `data-listcount="2" data-list1="one" data-list2="two"`), so it wouldn't take as much space, then when you append it, give it an `id`, so when you hover again, you just need to check if it exist already and show it, rather than updating the existing one or creating a new one everytime.

Comment: The issue is that these tooltips are tied to client created content in a WordPress shortcode...so I can't really use data attributes since they will be adding a variety of content including images and videos. Make sense?

Comment: @RevConcept, I think you can still use `data` attributes, but it will take quite a lot of time to change the code though, but I'm not sure which one perform better and if it's worth the time. If you don't have any performance issue, I think it's ok to keep what you do now.